# Sorting/Filtering JSON based on certain property

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

So I got this response from an API.
I want to build a select box from all **types**, how do I extract only JSON related to **skill_level** from this JSON without using loops.

```
[
  {
    "id": 32,
    "name": "Beginner",
    "type": "skill_level"
  },
  {
    "id": 33,
    "name": "Intermediate",
    "type": "skill_level"
  },
  {
    "id": 34,
    "name": "Experienced",
    "type": "skill_level"
  },
  {
    "id": 35,
    "name": "Professional",
    "type": "skill_level"
  },
  {
    "id": 36,
    "name": "Expert",
    "type": "skill_level"
  },
  {
    "id": 37,
    "name": "Male",
    "type": "sex"
  },
  {
    "id": 38,
    "name": "Female",
    "type": "sex"
  },
  {
    "id": 39,
    "name": "Single",
    "type": "marital_status"
  },
  {
    "id": 40,
    "name": "Married",
    "type": "marital_status"
  },
  {
    "id": 41,
    "name": "Divorced",
    "type": "marital_status"
  },
  {
    "id": 42,
    "name": "Not Wish To Say",
    "type": "marital_status"
  }
]
```

Comment: are the `id`s always 32-36 for skill level?

Comment: Why would you not want to use loops?

Comment: Using underscore.js:  

`var skillLevelArray = _.filter(JSONData, function(item) { return item.type=="skill_level"; };`

Comment: @connexo I would not want to use loop because the json in my question is just a truncated chunk of the main json which I can post here. In other words its a heavy json data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
var skillLevels = data.filter(function(item) {
    return item.type === 'skill_level';
});
```

From the docs, this works as follows:

> The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

Assuming that `data` refers to the array you provided in your question, this will result with `skillLevels` being a new array containing all of the items where `item.type` was equal to `"skill_level"`.

Comment: thanks for your answer. how does this work? where is .filter coming from? is this a method in angularjs?

Comment: Hey, `.filter()` is available on all JavaScript arrays (it's a core part of the language, not something provided by Angular or other external library). Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks @mar777

Comment: Which ECMA Script Version was this introduced with?

Comment: @connexo It was introduced in ECMAScript 5.1 (it works in IE9+ and virtually all extant versions of other browsers). It's trivial to [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Polyfill) if you need <=IE8 support.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#filter):

```
$scope.data = ...;
$scope.filtered = _.filter($scope.data, { 'type': 'skill_level' });
```

This will return only the objects that have `skill_level` for `type`.

Comment: Absolutely, you just need to include it in your index.html.

Comment: Thanks man. I accepted @jmar777 answer because it works out of box, however I like Lodash seems more efficient and faster, been looking for a library like that. Thanks for your answer. An upvote for you.

Comment: I like the sexy syntax in lodash compared to Vanilla JS or even Underscore.js. It has to be noted, hough, that it comes with a price tag - 12k lines of code (lodash) compared to 1.5k (underscore).

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out that you can also do it this way in AngularJs:

```
<select id="sex" name="sex" ng-model="sex">
    <option ng-repeat="option in $scope.data | filter:{type: 'sex'}" value="{{option.id}}">{{option.name}}</option>
</select>
```